# Embedded image no longer click-able?

Tags: support, markdown

I was recently notified that my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/902758/remove-or-prevent-sidebar-from-opening-by-default-on-adobe-reader) was edited. It was a fine edit.

I was reviewing the edit history and noticed that the image was changed yet it remains exactly the same as far as I can tell.

I ended up trying to click the image in my question and it is no longer click-able.

[Example with click-able image](https://superuser.com/questions/966423/use-adblock-without-being-detected)

Not sure when this happened but did something change with Markdown?

Comment: See the answer below for why. I've fixed the link for you and it is now clickable.

Answer (score 2):

We can see the Markdown changes by clicking "side by side markdown" in [the revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/902758/revisions).

[image: latest revision]

The image appears to have been modified in the "side-by-side" view because part of the Markdown that produces the image was changed: the description, which is the `alt` attribute for the image.

Like text, images can be inside link markup. Interestingly, image markup looks a lot like link markup in Markdown; a preceding `!` before the opening bracket makes an image instead of a link. The above image has this Markdown:

```
[![latest revision][1]][1]
```

The image embed is provided by `![latest revision][1]`; the wrapping around that makes it clickable. (The link target is the same as the image source, the #1 URL at the bottom of my post's source.)

Looking through the revision history of the post with the non-clickable image, I don't see any revision where the image was a link. You could wrap it in the link markup, if you like.

Tip: you can see the full Markdown source for a post by clicking the "source" link in the revision history, or by starting an edit.